# cannot install apt-fast in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: package-management, dependencies, apt-fast

I tried to install apt-fast in my Ubuntu 12.10 but it shows following error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies
apt-fast : depends: aria2 but is not going to install
build essential : depends : g++(>=4.4.4.3) but is not going to be installed
depends: dpkg-dev (>=1.13.5) but is not going to be installed"
```

Please help me because these errors are shown everywhere - whatever I want to install.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following in Terminal to install Apt-fast.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

Afterwards, a prompt will open up asking you to choose between apt-get and aptitude. Again, another prompt pops up asking to to choose between Axel and Aria2c (download managers). Choose the ones you like and you're done.

Now, simply replace apt-get in commands with apt-fast. Examples below:

```
sudo apt-fast install chromium-browser
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

Done. Enjoy your increased apt-get download speeds.

This should work because its the stable version, can you please post what you typed into the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa/17226-ubuntu-1204-lts-apt-fast-a-shellscript-wrapper-for-apt-get

> apt-fast is a shellscript wrapper for apt-get that can drastically improve apt download times by downloading packages in parallel, with multiple connections per package. It uses axel or aria2c as a download manager.
>
> Once you've setup apt-fast, you can use it like apt-get.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-fast update
> sudo apt-fast dist-upgrade or sudo apt-fast upgrade
> sudo apt-fast install packagename
> ```
>
> #### Install and set up apt-fast in Ubuntu
>
> open up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) window and just execute following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install apt-fast axel
> ```
>
> After installation, configure apt-fast to use axel as download manager:
>   edit the configuration file:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/apt-fast.conf
> ```
>
> remove # before following "_DOWNLOADER" line and save the file
>
> ```bsh
> # axel:
> _DOWNLOADER='cat /tmp/apt-fast.list | xargs -l1 axel -n ${_MAXNUM} -a' # axel
> ```
>
> Now, run this command and then you can use apt-fast as apt-get
>
> ```
> sudo apt-fast update
> ```